# What Are "npm run dev" and "npm run prod"

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, node-modules, laravel-mix

I use the following command to bundle my scripts via the Laravel Mix module:

```
npm run dev // Compile scripts.

npm run prod // Compile and minify scripts.
```

Are these native npm commands or custom Laravel Mix commands? Where are they defined?

I noticed they are listed as "scripts" in the Laravel package.json. What exactly are these scripts, custom commands for Webpack via Laravel Mix?

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Comment: You seem to have found what they are and where they're defined, so what's your question exactly? They're NPM [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts).

Comment: What do they run, cross-env or webpack.js? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are indeed the scripts as defined in the `package.json` file as you discovered. The values are run by your shell (so, for example, `bash`, `zsh`, etc. on UNIX-like operating systems).

One key thing to note is that the `node_modules/.bin` directory is added to `PATH` before executing. So, in the case of the two scripts you're asking about, `cross-env` can be found in `node_modules/.bin` (because it's almost certainly specified as a devDependency elsewhere in the `package.json`) as long as you've already run `npm install` or `npm ci` within the project directory.

Comment: Yeah, cross-env is listed in devDependencies. Thanks for your help, it helped me understand how these two custom scripts function, which is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

Those commands are used at any project which supports JSON files on NPM. Regarding OP questions:

> Are these native npm commands or custom Laravel Mix commands? Where
> are they defined?

- `npm`: One could say that it is a command native to the system, for [calling Node Package Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/) program. In Windows, for example, it should be the default command for calling npm from any console.
- `run`: It is a command native to npm. More information [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script). Keep in mind this is an aliases to the original command `run-script`.
- `dev` and `prod`: They're user defined.

  - `dev`: Used for running the specific commands for serving the project, to any server, to live development. In the case of a web page, you'll see your web page in the browser, and any change you make to the HTML code, for example, will be reflected immediately in the page you see in your browser.
  - `prod`: Compiles all the necessary files for production. Final product. In the case of a web page, for example, the HTML, CSS, and JS files you'll handle to the client. The result of running this command, it is expected to be one single folder with all the afore mentioned content.

> I noticed they are listed as "scripts" in the Laravel package.json.
> What exactly are these scripts, custom commands for Webpack via
> Laravel Mix?

- `"dev": "npm run development"`: Runs the commandment immediately below, which is: `"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`. What this line of code does, depends on what dependencies you have on your project (see the `node_modules` folder, and read their respective documentation).
- `"prod": "npm run production"`: It has the same description than the item above, but for `npm run prod`

Comment: You may also find this reference of some use: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/light-server#usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/light-server#usage)